# Is "des" capitalized when used to describe a country?

Tags: grammaire

For example: The country "The Comoros" is "Les Comores" in French.

As we know, in French; if there is a "de" and a "les", they form a "des". Now since in a sentence, "de" would not be capitalized; however "les" will be due to it's nature of relating to a proper noun.

So now I have "des". How am I supposed to write "of the Comoros" in French? Is "des" capital or not? Or is it a completely different way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that would be ***des** Comores*, e.g. "*L'archipel **des** Comores*".

In fact, even ***les*** in ***les** Comores* is not capitalized simply because articles used with or inside country names and articles used inside city names are not capitalized in French, unless the article is not written in French, e.g.:

> *Je part de **La** Nouvelle-Orléans vers **le** Québec.*
>
> *Je suis à Mantes-**la**-Jolie.*
>
> *Je navigue vers **les** Bahamas.*
>
> *Où se trouve l'ambassade de **El** Salvador* or *… l'ambassade **du** Salvador*

Of course, when the article starts a sentence, it must always be capitalized:

> **Les** Comores se trouvent dans **l**'Océan Indien.

Initial articles in town are capitalized, we write ***La** Rochelle, **Le** Havre, **La** Haye* and ***Des** Moines*. In the latter case, *des* grammatical function has been lost (we say the ugly *la ville **de Des** Moines*), probably because the first part of the name was dropped as it used to be called *Fort-**des**-Moines*.

When the article is modified (***à Le*** and ***à Les***), it loses its capitalization:

> *Je vais **au** Havre*.
>
> *Je suis **aux** Sables-d'Olonne.*

Comment: About the exception on article "Des": I think it is also related to Historical naming. No unique rule fully applies. There is other exceptions for sure. This answer should be accepted. +1

Comment: Pourquoi la majuscule à "La Nouvelle-Orléans" ?

Comment: @SimonDéchamps I'm unable to find a definitive answer. It seems there is no agreement about it so both capitalized and non capitalized form are used. The Bescherelle capitalizes articles in city names.